# java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have been trying to get Scanner to accept user input for 12 hours
today. Earlier attempts work fine. I also tried to used
**BufferedReader**.

It seems to never reach the line:

`userMenuInput = reader.nextInt();`

I am not accepting defeat.

```
public int displayMenu2() {

    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("        MENU 2              ");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("PRESS 2 - Finalize sale");
    System.out.println("PRESS 3 - Cancel sale");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");

    int userMenuInput = 0;

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print(">> ");

    //Error HERE....

    userMenuInput = reader.nextInt();

    if (userMenuInput == 0) {

        userMenuInput = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("" + reader.nextInt());
    }

    reader.close();

    //BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //System.out.print(">> ");

    //String inputString = reader2.readLine();
    //inputString = reader2.readLine();

    //userMenuInput = Integer.parseInt ( inputString );
    //           
    //      while(userMenuInput != 2 || userMenuInput != 3 )
    //      {
    //         System.out.println("Please enter a valid input!");
    //         System.out.print(">>");
    //         inputString = reader2.readLine();
    //         inputString = reader2.readLine();
    //         userMenuInput = Integer.parseInt ( inputString );
    //}

    return userMenuInput;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
--------------------------
    MENU 2              
--------------------------

PRESS 2 - Finalize sale
PRESS 3 - Cancel sale
--------------------------
>> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
  at CashRegister.displayMenu2(CashRegister.java:263)
  at Driver.main(Driver.java:207)
```

Comment: Yes. Sad day. The exceptions thrown are: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: What does the [API documentation for Scanner.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) say might be the cause when it throws `NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: I'm not sure why it threw this one: NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted. I feel like this one would have been more appropriate:
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed. But, it was the Scanner, anyway. I think it had to do with the fact that I interfered with Java's ability to throw exceptions because of improper use of .close().  The program terminated poorly.  maybe ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help, William. Found the answer after reading a lot of contradictory information about whether or not to use .close(). I believe that because I am not competent with exception handling, my use of .close() got me into trouble ([Java IO: Exception Handling](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/io-exception-handling.html)).  There were a bunch of .close() in another class that let to the generation of this error, here.

I read in "Introduction to Java Programming," by Liang (10th ed), "Note: **If you use an IDE such as Eclipse or NetBeans,** **you will get a warning to ask you to close the input to prevent a potential resource leak**." (Which I did. Which I responded to adding .close()'s all over the place. Which is about the time that the program started to fail) "**Ignore the warning** because the input is automatically closed when your program is terminated. In this case, there will be no resource leaking." (page 39)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a similar program to take input from user using scanner class. This might be helpful:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println("        MENU 2              ");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("PRESS 2 - Finalize sale");
        System.out.println("PRESS 3 - Cancel sale");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print(userInput);
    }
}
```